# How to set options for embedded charts in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

First I couldn't find how to set the dimension for an embedded chart.

The solution to that was setOption('width', width) + setOption('height', height)

Now I want to set the min and max values for the vertical axis when I create the chart.

Google's doc just says ...

setOption(name, value)

Sets advanced options for this chart. See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference for what options are available.

... but I cant find the name of the available options there.

I.e. I lack the method setDimension(pixwidth, pixheight) in the EmbeddedChartBuilder ...

```
function addChart(dataSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Graphs');


  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(dataSheetName);
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .addRange(dataRange)
  .setPosition(5, 1, 0, 0)
  // .setDimension(800, 400)    // This method does not exist!

  .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: I can't find any reference for the "advanced options" in that link, other than a few examples in the code samples.

Answer (score 3):

I found it ...

```
.setOption('width', 700)
.setOption('height', 200)
```

Comment: Where did you find the options? Are they listed out anywhere? I can't find them

Answer (score 0):

I found a list of chart options here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options

The `width` and `height` options you mentioned are present there.

Answer (score 0):

As lacton's answer mentioned, the documentation is under [the guides section](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/) of the site linked in the question. There is a section for each chart type listed on the left-hand side of the page, and each contains a list of configuration options which details what you can use in apps script's `.setOption()`.

The maximum and minimum values for the vertical axis are set with `vAxis.maxValue` and `vAxis.minValue` respectively, e.g. `.setOption('vAxis.maxValue',100)`.